# Select Element based on HTML Cell Contents with Selenium Java

Tags: java, html, selenium

I have an HTML table with each cell containing a checkbox and a color name.
[HTML color table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj8bA.png)

I need to tick the checkbox of any given color. The checkbox itself has no good identifiers indicating what color it's selecting.

I tried:

```
WebElement color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Violet']"));
color.click();
```

Obviously that doesn't work as it selects and sends a click to the text itself.

**How can I select the checkbox that's inside the same <td> element?**

Here's the HTML:

[A snip from Chrome for readability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQayP.png)

```html
<td width="25%" valign="top" align="center"><nobr><input type="checkbox" name="489_1111111111" value="55069" onclick="unselectBoth(489)" checked="">Select color:</nobr><br>Dill Green


</td>
```

Comment: Can you post the html of the element in question. What you should be doing is clicking the checkbox which is located beside the text.

Comment: I added the HTML to the question. I don't have any good way to identify the checkbox, I don't think. It has a unique "value" that correlates to the color, but I'm not completely sure of that and I also have no control over it. Can I find the color name with an xpath contains() and then use preceding-sibling to get the checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select the checkbox using the following Xpath :

```
String myColor = "Dill Green";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='myTableID']//td[contains(.,'"+myColor +"')]//input")).click();
```